# Gameloop not continuously running to make my enemies move

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, canvas

I'm making a game with an enemies class which will hold a bunch of enemies and I just have to call `enemy_spawn.enemy1(number_of_enemies)`. My enemy is printing but only 1 is showing up, also it is not moving at all(currently its just supposed to move horizontally).

```
export default class Enemies {
  constructor() {
    this.enemy1_list = [];
  }
  enemy1(number_of_enemies) {
    var i;
    var j;
    for (i = 0; i < number_of_enemies; i++) {
      var ex = getRndInteger(100, 200);
      var ey = getRndInteger(60, 110);
      this.enemy1_list[i] = [ex, ey];
    }
    for (j = 0; j < number_of_enemies; j++) {
      // var ex, var ey = enemy1_list[j];
      var pos = this.enemy1_list[j];

      img.onload = () => {
        ctx.drawImage(img, pos[0], pos[1]);
        pos[0]++;
      };
    }
  }
}
```

**My main javascript code**

```
import Enemies from "/src/enemies.js";

let canvas = document.getElementById("gamescreen");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const GAME_WIDTH = 1000;
const GAME_HEIGHT = 600;

ctx.fillStyle = "lightblue";
ctx.fillRect(800, 0, 200, 600);

//dollar image here
const img = new Image();
img.src = "/img/extras/dollar.png";
img.onload = () => {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 792, 0);
};

//lives image here
const img2 = new Image();
img2.src = "/img/extras/lives.png";
var widthimg2 = 40;
var heightimg2 = 40;
img2.onload = () => {
  ctx.drawImage(img2, 805, 70, widthimg2, heightimg2);
};

let enemy1_spawn = new Enemies();

function gameloop() {
  enemy1_spawn.enemy1(3);

  requestAnimationFrame(gameloop);
}

gameloop();
```

[image: Image to see what's happening]
This picture might help visualise what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: You made a typo. `i++` should be `j++`. I vote to close this question as a typo.

Comment: What is `img`? If an HTMLImageElement, where is its src changed? If outside of the loop, normal that the onload event doesn't fire more than once.

Comment: @Kaiido How do I make onload keep updating it's value?

Comment: You don't. You wait once that your image loads, then you start your update loop and you use the loaded resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (j = 0; j < number_of_enemies; i++)
```

propably should be

```
for (j = 0; j < number_of_enemies; j++)
```

increase j instead of i

Comment: Thank you, that was the error, however my code still doesn't seem to be working, any ideas?

Comment: can you add some more context? what is the image and context variable? what are you trying to achieve.
One thing i spotted right away was ```this.enemy1_list[i] = (ex, ey);``` which propably should be ```this.enemy1_list[i] = [ex, ey];```

Comment: Please take a look now.

Comment: that does not really help. but be aware that the ```image.onload``` function will only be called once after the image first finished loading. so propably the code inside it where you try to draw the pixel will never be executed.

Comment: How do I keep updating the value of onload?